# Scope dependency to view model

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, prism

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms application that uses Prism 7. I have dependencies registered in the DI container as transient but is there any way to have them scoped to ViewModel like they are scoped to the current web request?

Comment: What is the use case? If you register them transiently and inject them into the view model, their scope _is_ the view model, isn't it? The container won't (shouldn't) dispose stuff for you, anyway, that's done by the view model when navigated away.

Comment: @Haukinger If I have two dependencies that depend on the other hand have a dependency of the same type that type will be created twice.